# jQuery - on page load select optgoup and children in second select by a default selected option in a parent select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optgroup

I have a select "usercountry" that has a predefined option selected when the page loads. I have a second select organized with optgroup country and child option state. I have a jQuery script that will change/show the optgroup and child option states accordingly when the usercountry is chosen. The problem is when the page loads with "United States" preselected I need the optgroup United States preloaded.

HTML:

```
<select name="usercountry" id="usercountry" class="required">
        <option value="">-- Please Choose --</option>
        <option value="13">Australia</option>
        <option value="38">Canada</option>
        <option value="223" selected>United States</option>
        <option value="239">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<select name="userstate" id="userstate" class="required">
             <option value="" selected>Please Choose..</option>
       <optgroup label="Australia">
             <option value="New South Wales">New South Wales</option>
             <option value="Northern Territory">Northern Territory</option>
             <option value="Queensland">Queensland</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="Canada">
             <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
             <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
             <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
             <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="United States">
             <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
             <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
             <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
             <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
             <option value="California">California</option>
             <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
             <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
       </optgroup>
       <optgroup label="Zimbabwe">
             <option value="Bulawayo">Bulawayo</option>
             <option value="Harare">Harare</option>
             <option value="Manicaland">Manicaland</option>
             <option value="Midlands">Midlands</option>
       </optgroup>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
// sets the option group using the same code you already use for on-country-change
    function setOptGroup() {
var state_province = $('#userstate option, #userstate optgroup');
    state_province.hide();
// EDIT: this line won't retrieve selected country when page has just been loaded
//$("#userstate optgroup[label='" + $(this).find(':selected').html() + "']")
// this line works
    $("#userstate optgroup[label='" + $('#usercountry option:selected').text() + "']")
        .children()
        .andSelf()
        .show();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // set up the USA option group when the page is loaded
    setOptGroup();

// your present code - refactored a bit
$('#usercountry').change(setOptGroup); // edit to fix typo
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the jsFiddle of Annabel's suggestion
http://jsfiddle.net/goodegg/phj8q/
EDIT: The Code above works thanks to Annabel, see the ejsFiddle above for the final version

Comment: I made the appropriate edits and updated the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/goodegg/phj8q/ but this still Does Not Work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put your code in a `$(document).ready()` function?

Assuming your code does what you want when the user selects a different country, this is what you want to change your code to:

```
// sets the option group using the same code you already use for on-country-change
function setOptGroup() {
    var state_province = $('#userstate option, #userstate optgroup');
    state_province.hide();
    // EDIT: this line won't retrieve selected country when page has just been loaded
    //$("#userstate optgroup[label='" + $(this).find(':selected').html() + "']")
    // this line works
    $("#userstate optgroup[label='" + $('#usercountry').val() + "']")
        .children()
        .andSelf()
        .show();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // set up the USA option group when the page is loaded
    setOptGroup();

    // your present code - refactored a bit
    $('#usercountry').change(setOptGroup); // edit to fix typo
});
```

The document.ready function will run once - when the page has finished loading. It's normal with jQuery to put a lot of code here.

Comment: It's working as far as when you change the usercountry select the corresponding optgroup is selected in the second select. The problem is when the page first loads the Parent select has the United States as the default selected option and the second select is empty. I hope that makes sense. I just need the second select to have the optgroup matching the preselected option of the parent select loaded when the page loads.

Comment: Hi Annabel, No i doesn't preload the "United States" optgroup when the page loads. The userstate select is blank. I think there is also a typo in your code. should it be $('#usercountry').change(setOptGroup); instead of $('#usercountry').change(setOptionGroup); I changed it but still didn't work.

Comment: I don't see a typo. The first Select has an option for the United States and the second Select has an optgroup for the United States. Did you look at the jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, look at **line 5** in the HTML pane. You've got 'Sates' twice.

Comment: And it's the same in line 5 of the code you pasted in the original question.

Comment: ok, sorry Annabel. I see it now and fixed it. I also changed the option values in the Parent select to ID's like my application. I fixed it the jsFiddle also but it still doesn't work. What am I missing now?

Comment: `$(this).find(':selected')` was not selecting USA when page first loaded. See edited version of initial answer.