# One drop down box helps populates the other

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to insert data into a MySQL table that uses two drop down menus. The first is a list of parks and the second a list of rides. The second drop down box should only display items linked to the first by the column 'park_id'. I need a simple way for the second box to populate based on the first's selection.

This is the form so far:

```
<tr><td>Select Park:</td>
    <td><select name="park_id">
    <option value="">Select Park</option>

<?php   foreach ($res as $row) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $row['park_id'], $row['name'] );
 } ?>
    </select></td></tr>


    <tr><td>Select Ride:</td>
    <td><select name="ride_id">
    <option value="">Select Ride</option>

<?php   foreach ($res2 as $row2) {
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>' . PHP_EOL, $row2['ride_id'], $row2['name'] );
 } ?>
    </select></td></tr>
```

So somehow a query needs to run after selecting a park and use '$park_id = $row[park_id]' to help generate the results for the 'Select Ride' dropdown.

This is the query I need to use for the second drop down:

```
$qry2 = "SELECT ride_id, name FROM tpf_rides WHERE park_id = $park_id ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Can anyone talk me through this? Also my skill are very limited so a relatively simple solution would be great.
Thanksark

Comment: if you don't want to reload the page after the first select, you need to use ajax

Comment: it will require javascript either way, but if you don't use ajax: you will need javascript to submit the form each time the first dropdown selection is changed. then on the server side, you will need to prevent the second query from running if no value was selected on the first dropdown.

Comment: No need to use ajax - you can download data for all the parks and rides when you first load the page. UNLESS you have a lot of parks with a lot of rides (over 60).

Comment: @annabel unfortunately there are 100's of parks and 1000's of rides

Answer (score 1):

For this you will have to get into AJAX, and I highly recommend using jQuery's implementation. You will also need to get a good grip on JSON string coding and decoding.

The basic Idea of your code will be like so:

```
// listen for user to change the <select> item
$('select#park').on('change', function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getrides.php' // send a park id to this script
        ,cache: false  // do not cache results in browser
        ,type: 'POST' // send POST to getrides.php
        ,data: {'park_id': $('select#park').val()} // getrides.php will receive $_POST['park_id']
        ,dataType: 'json' // this AJAX call expects a JSON string as a return value
        ,success: function(data){ // the data variable will be converted to an array from JSON

            // check out all your data
            console.log(data);

            // loop through your array
            $.each(data, function(index, info){

                // see your array indexes
                console.log(index);

                // see data in each array item
                console.log(info);
            });
        }
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can also load all of the parks and rides into a Javascript array and based on what the user chooses from the dropdown then populate the second dropdown with those array members.

```
<script>
var rides = new Array();
rides['park1'].push('ride1');
rides['park1'].push('ride2');
rides['park1'].push('ride3');
rides['park1'].push('ride4');
rides['park1'].push('ride5');
rides['park2'].push('ride1');
rides['park2'].push('ride2');
rides['park2'].push('ride3');
rides['park2'].push('ride4');
rides['park2'].push('ride5');

// listen for user to change the <select> item
$('select#park').on('change', function(){

    // clear current DD options
    $('select#rides').html();

    // loop through array of available rides for selected park
    $.each(rides[''+$(this).val()+''], function(index, value){

        // dynamically create the proper DD options
        $('select#rides').append('<option>'+value+'</option>');
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write another file that uses the id of the first selected from the bikes list  value to load the options of the second select  tag the rides list

then make an empty div on the first file that will be loaded with the result  of the second file  which is the list of rides

```
$(function() {
  $('#ID_of_the_park_selecttag').change(function() {
    var value = $("#ID_of_the_park_selecttag").find('option:selected').text();
         $("#ID_OF_THE_DIV").html("");
      $("#ID_OF_THE_DIV").load('theOtherFile.php', {"bikename":value } );// value is the value of the select option from the first <select tag>
  });});
```

then on the  second file you can get the value of the bike selected as `$_POST['bikename']` and do your query then fill the list

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently myself.  Here's what I did, feel free to use what makes sense to you.  I tried what seemed like a simple way to myself.

```
<select name="department_list" id="department_list" onchange="$('#singleUser').load('yourextraphppage.php?nid='+this.value);">
<option value='none'>Select a department</option>
```

Then load your first select list with data and close the select tag...  Add a blank div where you want the 2nd select.  I used the value from the first select list for my parameter for the 2nd select list's query.  (it was the foreign key in the 2nd table for the 2nd select list)

```
<div id="singleUser" class="singleUser">
</div>
```

Last, you need the additional PHP page that you called from the first select list.  Here's a barebones version of my code.

```
echo "<option value='none'>Select user</option>";

try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT dm.empid AS empid, u.name AS name FROM mytable dm
                JOIN mytable2 u ON dm.empid = u.id 
                WHERE dm.deptid = :id
                ORDER BY u.name");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $empid = $r['empid'];
            $userName = $r['name'];

           echo "<option value='".$empid."'>".$userName."</option>"; 

}
echo "</select>";
echo "</p>";
$db = null;
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "An Error occurred!";
    }
```

I hope this helps.  I'm rather busy so I can't go in detail explaining it at the moment.  I'll check back later to see if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was helping somebody a similar page a day or say ago:

2 dropdown selects and the list of options in the second dropdown changed according to the choice selected in the first.

The solution involved the use of `<optgroup>` elements within the `<select>` and **jQuery** (which is not all that easy for a beginner but at least you can copy the code.

See here for the question: [jQuery - on page load select optgoup and children in second select by a default selected option in a parent select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197361/jquery-on-page-load-select-optgoup-and-children-in-second-select-by-a-default)

And here to see the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/goodegg/phj8q/
(although there is a mistake in it).

**EDIT**

Go here for my forked version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/annabels/7xksa/